# what fundamental in phoneGap build?

Tags: ios, cordova, build, phonegap, ipa

## does any one can tell me how does phoneGap build work https://build.phonegap.com/?

what can i do if i build this server like that or tell me any opensource like that, i want create one too as study.

#### i want create a website like that:

> Simply upload your web assets - a ZIP file of HTML, CSS and JavaScript, or a single index.html file - to Build hybrid app useing cordova

Answer (score 0):

i for myself prefer Cordova to develop hybrid apps.

The begin is to install everything like described here:

[Cordova installation guide](https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted)

After that and with a new fresh project file, which is explained in the install guide, you can start to develop your hybrid app. All your HTML files going to /www folder, JS to /www/js/ and CSS files are moved to /www/css/. After that you have to look that all bindings for these files inside html are okay, like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">`

have to be:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">`

the same for all included js files, they have to point at the js folder and then the file. After that you can check your app by simple:

`cordova run <platform name>`

platform name is a placeholder, should be, ios, android, or so on. But check if you add these platform before to prevend error messages.

If you need more help, just ask ;)

Have a nice day.

Comment: thanks, i followed by cordova guide and no errors in android, but when i try ios build it shows: No iOS profile matching 'xxxxxx/xxxxx' found:  Xcode couldn't find a profile matching 'xxxxx/xxxxx'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor , but i did this already(use build.json and apple cer file and .mobileprovision file)

Comment: You have this in your build.json?
`{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "provisioningProfile": "******",
            "developmentTeam": "******",
            "packageType": "development"
        },
        "release": {
            "provisioningProfile": "******",
            "developmentTeam": "*******",
            "packageType": "app-store"
        }
    }
}`

Sorry editing in code isn´t possible as i know so far. Thats why this code is written that bad.      For the solution, have you tried to build without a connected device (iphone, ipad)?

Comment: Yes, i followed [https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html]
this ios guide

I want to build ios .ipa, i perform: cordova build ios --device --release --buildConfig=./build.json, but got errors again

Comment: What errors do you get? I´m sure we find a solution with more information.

Comment: I asked a question in details in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068742/how-can-i-build-cordova-ios-app-ipa-with-cordova-cli-etc-cordova-build-ios-d], thanks for reply